# How to compare current view Id from the Activity with other layouts id

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-navigation

I have been trying to compare my current view from the activity with other random layout file using:

```
if (this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().getId() == 
        findViewById(R.layout.layout_1).getId())
```

The above code is not working.

The respective ID's displayed are -1 and 22566789

Is it possible to compare them? Please let me know any other method to compare them.

Comment: why do you want to compare? your comparision will never be true

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you showed is that you call `findViewById(R.layout.layout_1)`. This should be returning null. `R.layout.layout_1` is not a View ID, it is a layout ID, and thus `findViewById()` should fail.

If you know the ID of the root view in your second layout, use that (in the format `R.id.my_root_view`).

If you want to compare the actual layout IDs, I would recommend storing the current layout ID whenever you call `setContentView()` (assuming this is an Activity).

Answer (score 0):

Simple ex I wrote for you;

```
public void findId(View root, int id){
    if(root instanceof ViewGroup){
        for(int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup)root).getChildCount(); ++i){
            findId(((ViewGroup) root).getChildAt(i), id);
        }
    }

    if(root.getId() == id)
    {
        Log.i("view","in it");
    }
}
```

Call method;

```
    View root = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content); // activity contentview

    findId(root, R.id.textView1);
```